# Sorting S, M, L etc clothing sizes from data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to re order the following divs so that they are placed in the correct order (s,m,l,xl) based on their data-value.

```
<div class="size-swatches">
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="m"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="s"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="xl"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="l"></div>
</div>
```

For numerical data (8, 10, 12 etc) I've been using the following script but I'm not sure how I would approach this for s,m,l,xl

```
var $wrapper = $('.size-swatches');
$wrapper.find('.swatch').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.dataset.value - +b.dataset.value;
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

The goal is to order the divs like this:

```
<div class="size-swatches">
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="s"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="m"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="l"></div>
    <div class="swatch size" data-value="xl"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can define an array which stores the correct order you want the values to be sorted in. Then you can create your own `sort()` logic which compares the indexes of the values within that array, something like this:

```js
var order = ['s', 'm', 'l', 'xl'];

var $wrapper = $('.size-swatches');
$wrapper.find('.swatch').sort(function(a, b) {
  var aSize = $(a).data('value'), bSize = $(b).data('value');
  return order.indexOf(aSize) - order.indexOf(bSize);
}).appendTo($wrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="size-swatches">
  <div class="swatch size" data-value="m">M</div>
  <div class="swatch size" data-value="s">S</div>
  <div class="swatch size" data-value="xl">XL</div>
  <div class="swatch size" data-value="l">L</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had sort of same situation. i come up with a solution which is short and optimized if you are using `ES6`. intersection technique can be used here between two sets. 
I used it as follows:

```js
const filteredValues = ['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl']
    .filter(x => new Set(['xs', 'xs', 'm', 'l', 'xxl']).has(x))
console.log(filteredValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sizes = ['s', 'm', 'xs', 'l', 'xxl', 'xl', 'xxxxs']

const sortSizes = sizes => sizes.map(s => s.toLowerCase()).map(size => ({
    size,
    points: size === 'm' ? 0 : size.length * (size.includes('s') ? -1 : 1),
  })).sort((a, b) => a.points - b.points)
  .map(({
    size
  }) => size)


console.log(sortSizes(sizes)) // => ['xxxxs', 'xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl']
```